# WCF PerSesson InstanceContextMode prevents generation of proxies using SVCUtil

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, svcutil.exe

I have a Windows Service hosted WCF Web Service. I've been generating proxies using SVCUTIL and things have been working fine, but today I changed the *InstanceContextMode* from **InstanceContextMode.Single** to **InstanceContextMode.PerSession** and now I get the below error which I can't isolate. I can reliably recreate the error by changing nothing other then this one setting. Any ideas???

Here is the Error Message from SVCUTIL

> Generating metadata files... EXEC : error : There was an error
>   exporting the service type:
>   Host.Services.MyService.
>
> ```
> An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension:
> ```
>
> System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>   contract:
>   http://MySoftware/ServiceContracts/2011/02:IMyService

The service interface is as follows:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = Namespace.Current, SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface IMyService
```

The service implementation is ***now*** configured as follows:

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = Namespace.Current, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class MyService : IMyService
```

Here is the current setting in my config file for the data contract serializer

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1000000" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be related to the instance context mode.
Try the following:

1. Use an HTTP sniffer, such as fiddler, to see the returned WSDL file. Make sure you are not getting an error page instead of the wsdl file.
2. If you are getting a WSDL file and not an error page, save that file, change the service back to single, get the WSDL and compare the two WSDL files to find the problem.

Comment: I deployed the change to a test environment and was able to confirm that the product still works as expected (`functionally`). I also confirmed the instancing behaviour changed as expected using the SeviceModel Performance Counters. I still cannot create proxies with SVCUtil. I am still reviewing the WSDL but do not expect to find any change since this is purely a change in the host behaviour and not a contract change for consumers. To reiterate, the only change was the InstanceContextMode

Comment: Instance context mode only affects how the service host creates instances for your service type. Accessing metadata doesn't require creating an instance, and therefore shouldn't affect when using svcutil. Try turning on WCF tracing on the service side and check the logs for any error.

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunetally this did not uncover anything.